# Checked checkboxes is unchecked when i scroll listview in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Below is my `GetView()` method in adapter class, when I scroll the list view by selecting one checkbox.  After scrolling back to initial position checked checkbox is getting unchecked.

```cs
    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView; 
        var item = mMyList [position];
        //View holder
        MyViewHolder holder = null;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new MyViewHolder ();
            view = mcontext.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.listview_layout, null);
            holder.mChecked = view.FindViewById<CheckBox> (Resource.Id.chkBox);
            holder.Name = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.Name);
            holder.StartDate = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.startDate);
            holder.EndDate = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.endDate);
            holder.Desc = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.Desc);
            view.SetTag (holder);
        } else {
            holder = (MyViewHolder)view.Tag;
        }
        holder.Name.SetText (item.Name, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        holder.StartDate.SetText (item.StartDate, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        holder.EndDate.SetText (item.EndDate, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        holder.Desc.SetText (item.Description, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple!
You just need to store this "states" of checkboxes,because everytime when you scroll your **listview**, GetView method will be called(to draw hided items, Android reuses rows).

In your DataContext, for e.g. List<**MyClass**> , where MyClass represents:

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string SecondName {get;set;}
        public bool IsChecked {get;set;}
    }
```

try to add bool property(in this case **IsChecked**) for state of Checkbox.
And after this,in your GetView **method** write something likes this:

```
holder.mChecked.Checked = MyList [position].#YourBoolProperty#;
```

Btw i just write that on the fly.
Also,if something isn't clear for you, try to check [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23637/android-checkbox-listview-checkboxes-automcatically-check-uncheck-upon-scrolling) or [this](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html).
Hope that helps!